# Local service development is not available in WebMethods Designer 8.2

Tags: plugins, designer, webmethods

The local service development option is not available in WebMethods Designer 8.2.1. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin for the local service development can be downloaded using the Software AG Installer. You need to be licensed, to download the plug-in.